# Stopping audio on fragment in Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, class, event-handling, reveal.js

I happily use Reveal.js for presentation purposes, but now I want to create MOOCS using the fine script. I want to put an audio clip with each fragment, that starts playing when the fragment is shown. So far that works fine using the eventListener method to start and pause audio in my slideshow. However, given the nature of this method, the audio or video will continue when the next fragment is shown, as it is dependent on the status of 'fragmentshown' or 'fragmenthidden'. (see below)

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'fragmentshown', function( event ) {
    var audio = event.fragment.querySelector( 'audio' );
    if( audio ) {
    audio.play();
    }});
Reveal.addEventListener( 'fragmenthidden', function( event ) {
    var audio = event.fragment.querySelector( 'audio' );
    if( audio ) {
    audio.pause();
    }});
```

Is there an easy way to extend this using the 'current-fragment' class that's added to the fragment that is current (duh), to pause (or better yet: stop) the audio when the class is passed on to the next fragment? I'm sure there is, but I'm a novice and would really appreciate a heads up here. It would be great for moocing purposes if this would be part of the code. I get lots of requests for it from teaching colleagues at our university.

Comment: Ah. I solved it. Simply used classList.contains to trigger an audio play on class "current-fragment", and a pause using an else-statement.

Comment: Hi, Could you elaborate this on code pelase? Also write that as an answer so we can vote.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a MOOC you can use the `audio-slideshow` plugin that does the job for you. The plugin allows you to specify an audio file for each slide and fragment. Alternatively, it automatically checks if there is an audio file for the slide and fragment based on the reveal.js indices, e.g. for the second horizontal and first vertical slide ist checks whether there is a file `audio/1.0.ogg`.

You can also record the audio while presenting using the `slideshow-recorder` plugin or use text-to-speech.

You can find a demo [here](http://courses.telematique.eu/audio-slideshow/)  and the plugin [here](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js/tree/audio-slideshow/plugin/audio-slideshow)

Asvin